# display excel output in jframe

Tags: java, excel, swing, jframe, apache-poi

I am trying to get information from Excel to display it in JFrame.
My Code should get the information i want e.g. the header "name" and should display it in JFrame.

I couldn't find anything helpfull in google.
My code displays me the whole Excel sheet in the Eclipse Console.

It would be helpfull when someone can give an code example.
Below you can find the code how i dispaly my Excel sheet
Thank you in advance :)

```
public void csvmethods() throws IOException {

       OPCPackage pkg;
       try {
       pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:\\Users\\akurt1\\Documents\\Mappe1.xlsx"));

       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

       FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
       for (Row row : sheet) // iteration over row using for each loop
       {
           for (Cell cell : row) // iteration over cell using for each loop
           {
               switch (formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()) {
               case NUMERIC:
                   System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   break;
               case STRING: 
                   System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   break;
               }
           }

           System.out.println();
       }
       } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: A `JFrame` is a top level container of `Swing`. To display some text content in that container, you will need some other `Swing` components additionally. See [Using Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html).

Comment: I already have a class where i implement my JFrame.

Comment: Then this class needs a method which gets either a number (`cell.getNumericCellValue()`) or a string (`cell.getStringCellValue()`) and puts the contents of them into a component or components which will be displayed in that `JFrame`. That method then gets called instead of `System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue())` and `System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue())`.

Comment: The method i mentioned above is getting Strings out of the Excel sheet. Now what i am trying to is to display those Strings in the JFrame. But i don't know the code to do that. It would be nice if you could give me an example.